# Are there useful combinatorial constructions of grammars?

Tags: combinatorics, context-free-grammar, constructive-mathematics

By grammar  I mean a formal language grammar such as

$$
A \to aaBa \\
B \to bB | a
$$

You can define a tree recursively as, letting $T= $ set of all trees, as $T = \bullet \times SEQ(T)$, where $SEQ(T) = $ set of all non-empty sequences in $T$ (to see this a tree is a root node $\bullet$ connected (hence $\times$) to a finite sequence of child trees (some element of $SEQ(T)$), and from there compute the ordinary generating function $G(z)$ for it.  That is an example of a useful combinatorial construction of a tree.

Well, naively we could define a *context-free grammar (CFG)* $g$ as a sequence $g_1 \cdots g_n$ of elements from either our terminal alphabet $\Sigma$ or the $G$, the set of all CFGs.  Then we can define the size of $g$, $|g|$ to be the length of its immediate sequence $g_1 \cdots g_n$, $n$, plus the size of each of the CFG objects it refers to in its sequence.

One question, why don't I need to take the cartesian product with something as in $\bullet \times SEQ(T)$?

Anyway, that definition of grammar size is the same usual one defined by *smallest grammar* research.

So we said $G = SEQ(G \cup \Sigma)$.  How does that help us compute the OGF of $G$?  Well $SEQ(A)(z) = \frac{A(z)}{1-A(z)}$ can be found when $SEQ(A)$ is defined to be all non-empty sequences of objects in class $A$.

Thus, $G(z) = \frac{G(z) + \Sigma(z)}{1 - G(z) - \Sigma(z)}$.

I don't know where to take it from here or if that was a useful construction.  But that's a sample of what I meant in the title.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more careful in distinguishing between a *rule* from a CFG and the CFG itself. I can understand that you might want to identify the CFG with the rule which defines its initial non-terminal, but things might become clearer if you define the size of a rule as the number of symbols in its definition and the size of a grammar as the sum of the sizes of the rules reachable from its initial non-terminal. For a start, that immediately highlights the importance of the transitive closure, and suggests looking at graph combinatorics.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, if you could explain more in an answer, that would be great.

Comment: I don't have enough to make an answer, and you stand more chance of getting a more complete answer if I stick to comments. But Flajolet and Sedgewick's book on Analytic Combinatorics seems to address something related to context-free grammars, so you might want to try to find a copy.

Comment: I'm taking "Analytic Combinatorics" taught by Robert Sedgewick, on coursera.  Just found a link to the full book :E http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf